# how does the bash command "grep -v ":0"" work

Tags: bash, grep

I get a  command like  `grep -v ":0"` in a bash script.
it's used along with the watch command to show the number that was changed.
Anyone can explain what `":0"` means? thanks!

Comment: It means drop whatever line(s) contain `":0"`

Comment: -v is the inverse flag and so it will search for and show all entries that DON'T match ":0"

Comment: grep can take a huge list of arguments `grep [ -E | -F ] [ -i ] [ -h ] [ -H ] [ -L ] [ -r | -R ] [ -s ][ -u ] [ -v ] [ -w ] [ -x ] [ -y ] [ [ [ -b ] [ -n ] ] | [ -c | -l | -q ] ] [ -p [ Separator ] ] { [ -e PatternList ... ] [ -f PatternFile ... ] | PatternList ... } [ File ... ]`. Better to read [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

Comment: man grep would be a great start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In POSIX grep, `-v` is a matching control option to invert match.
In this usage case, it is telling grep to match all lines that do NOT contain the string ":0"

For more information, `man grep`

Comment: i thought :0 mean something special -_-!